# NoSuchMethodError while parsing xsd to generate classes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm new to JAXB. I'm trying to parse the xsd to generate the jaxb classes.
It works fine with other xsd files but the one I'm trying to parse now is generating exceptions. 
This is the stack trace

```
 parsing a schema...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>([Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;ZLcom/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/RuntimeAnnotationReader;ZZ)V
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo.getJAXBContext(BindInfo.java:332)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.AnnotationParserFactoryImpl$1.<init>(AnnotationParserFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.AnnotationParserFactoryImpl.create(AnnotationParserFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.createAnnotationParser(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.annotation.action0(annotation.java:48)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.annotation.enterElement(annotation.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.spawnChildFromEnterElement(NGCCHandler.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:500)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.revertToParentFromEnterElement(NGCCHandler.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.foreignAttributes.enterElement(foreignAttributes.java:50)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCHandler.spawnChildFromEnterElement(NGCCHandler.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:373)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:347)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.sendEnterElement(NGCCRuntime.java:378)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.complexType.enterElement(complexType.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.startElement(NGCCRuntime.java:219)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.SubtreeCutter.startElement(SubtreeCutter.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.startElement(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:144)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.startElement(IncorrectNamespaceURIChecker.java:113)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.CustomizationContextChecker.startElement(CustomizationContextChecker.java:188)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$SpeculationChecker.startElement(ModelLoader.java:455)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.VersionChecker.startElement(VersionChecker.java:98)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.JAXPParser.parse(JAXPParser.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$2.parse(ModelLoader.java:479)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:301)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMSpeculative(ModelLoader.java:496)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:366)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:313)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:74)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:96)
```

here is the xsd link:[XSD FILE](http://eeas.europa.eu/topics/sanctions-policy/8442/consolidated-list-of-persons-groups-and-entities-subject-to-eu-financial-sanctions_en)

Comment: Looks like incompatibe jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have incompatible libraries in your classpath.

Look which Version of `jaxb-xjc.jar` and `jaxb-impl` you have in your classpath

Comment: jaxb-xjc is 2.1.7 and jaxb-impl is 2.2_1

Comment: use the same Version of both jars.

Comment: It show this now `Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade`

Comment: @SagarNepali Do you use JRE or JDK as runtime?

Comment: **JRE** @Jens sir!

Comment: @SagarNepali Use the jdk. Only the jdk includes ths class

Comment: But @Jens sir, its been working fine with other schemas without pointing to jdk as runtime

Comment: @SagarNepali please try it. Maybe it is a Special tag that this class needs